# Python: Convert NoneType value to string

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

Newbie Question: Is it possible to convert a NoneType value to a string in Python?

```
def convert_string(value):
    new_value = str(value)
    return new_value

convert_string(value)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
NameError: name 'value' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no `None` here. You didn't define the name `value` as a global, only as a local name for the `convert_string()` function.

Comment: well, what is `value` for `convert_string(value)`? you need to define that first; say `value = None`

Comment: Yes, I know I didn't define the value in this case. The above function would hopefully convert any value (in this case a non-type variable) placed into the function to a string. the value is not a variable.

Comment: A none-type variable would be a defined variable that has the value `None`. In this case, you just have an undefined variable.

Answer (score 4):

When Python reaches the statement

```
convert_string(value)
```

it evaluates the argument `value` before calling the function. If `value` is not defined, then it raises a `NameError`:

```
NameError: name 'value' is not defined
```

`None` is a value. The variable `value` can be set to `None` with `value = None`. That is qualitatively different than not defining `value` at all.

Answer (score 0):

'value' is not defined in the line:

```
convert_string(value)
```

What you should write is

```
convert_string(None)
```

to properly test your function

Comment: Or, now that I think about it, just do str(None) at the command line to find out if it works...